# Android Animation Listener

Tags: android

`OnTouch` of an `ImageView` I'm starting a fade in animation:

```
    myImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    v.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation);
```

I know it's need an animation listener to find out when the animation is complete but how do I attach this so that I can get the view that the animation has just completed on... I want to set the visibility of the view after the animation is done.

Thanks

Comment: I want to know how to add an animation listener to an image view

Answer (score 133, accepted):

I think you need this.

```
fadeInAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }
});
```

Comment: If you only need to use a subset of the methods, you can use [AnimatorListenerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorListenerAdapter) and then only override the ones you need (e.g. onAnimationEnd())

Answer (score 27):

If you only need an end-action it would suffice to use `.withEndAction(Runnable)`

```
fadeInAnimation.withEndAction(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ... do stuff
    }
})
```

Comment: Only usable on API level 16 or higher

Comment: I am targeting API level 22 and don't see that `withEndAction()` as being available with TranslateAnimation class

Comment: @Roel could you refer my to link? i want to check `api` level

Comment: I can't see withEndAction also, same with @SomeoneSomewhere

Answer (score 7):

In case someone needs the solution in `kotlin`:

```
fadeInAnimation.setAnimationListener(object: Animation.AnimationListener {
        override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animation?) {
            TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation?) {
            TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animation?) {
            TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

    })
```

Answer (score 4):

### Using Kotlin

```
        //OR using Code
        val rotateAnimation = RotateAnimation(
                0f, 359f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f

        )
        rotateAnimation.duration = 300
        rotateAnimation.repeatCount = 2

        //Either way you can add Listener like this
        rotateAnimation.setAnimationListener(object : Animation.AnimationListener {

            override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animation?) {
            }

            override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animation?) {
            }

            override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation?) {

                val rand = Random()
                val ballHit = rand.nextInt(50) + 1
                Toast.makeText(context, "ballHit : " + ballHit, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        })

        ivBall.startAnimation(rotateAnimation)
```

Comment: hello, I have a question about your code, i used it for my question - can you maybe take a look at it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59253778/update-attributes-during-rotation-animation

Answer (score 3):

My function setAnimation

```
private Animation animateRoationLayout(Animation.AnimationListener animationListener) {
    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.level_expand_rotation);
    anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()); // for smooth animation
    anim.setAnimationListener(animationListener);
    return anim;
}
```

> Define Animation Listener :

```
final Animation.AnimationListener animationListener =new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Animation Have Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    };
```

> Set Animation For View :

```
  view.startAnimation(animateRoationLayout(animationListener));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `kotlin` and `androidx`. There are some event methods

```
Animator.doOnEnd
Animator.doOnStart
Animator.doOnCancel
Animator.doOnRepeat
Animator.doOnPause
Animator.doOnResume
```

Example

```
val animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(progressBar, View.ALPHA, 1f, 0.5f)
animator.doOnEnd {
    //
}
```