# Android View Animation cannot chain two animations of the same type

Tags: android, animation

I'm trying to chain two [View Animations](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html) of the same type, in this case alpha. Initially, I want my View to fade-out while translating left, then after this has completed the View should fade back in at the center of the screen.

I can get the animation to slide and fade to the left without issue, however, when I attempt to add a fade-in animation afterwards, no animation occurs, the alpha just abruptly changes to 0.2. I have tried playing with `fillAfter` and `fillBefore` but these don't seem to make a difference. I understand that View Animation has no impact on the actual properties of the View. Here is my code so far:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillBefore="false"
    android:fillEnabled="true"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">

    <translate
        android:duration="450"
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:toXDelta="-100%p" />

    <alpha
        android:duration="450"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.2" />

    <alpha
        android:duration="450"
        android:fromAlpha="0.2"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:startOffset="450" />
</set>
```

I know I could probably achieve the desired effect using Animation Listeners, however, an XML only solution would be more elegant in my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in android fillAfter and fillBefore are kind of tricky. let's try to follow their logic:

**fillAfter** = apply the changes AFTER the animation occurs

ok, that's wa easy... but what excactly is fillBefore?

**fillBefore** = apply **some** animation values BEFORE animation starts

so in your sample, remove fillBefore from your set and make **one** of the following changes:

```
    <!-- fillAfter = true -->
    <!-- after animation complete don't change opacity back to 1.. let it remain 0.2  -->
    <alpha
    android:duration="450"
    android:fillAfter="true"  
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:toAlpha="0.2" />

    <!-- fillBefore = true -->
    <!-- before animation starts set alpha to 0.2  -->
    <alpha
    android:duration="450"
    android:fillBefore="true"
    android:fromAlpha="0.2"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:startOffset="450" />
```

you don't need both - it just to show the meaning of those commands in your case

### EDIT: just to prove that this can be done :)

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillEnabled="true"
    android:shareInterpolator="true" >

    <translate
        android:duration="450"
        android:fillAfter="false"
        android:fillEnabled="true"
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:toXDelta="-100%p" />

    <alpha
        android:duration="450"
        android:fillAfter="false"
        android:fillEnabled="true"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0" />

    <alpha
        android:duration="450"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:fillBefore="false"
        android:fromAlpha="0.2"
        android:startOffset="450"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />

</set>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried both of those options, neither of them worked unfortunately. Same result, opacity jumps to 0.2 immediately. Translate works fine. No alpha animation, neither fade-out nor fade-in.

Comment: in the "worst" case you can split your animation into 2 different files and make the timing of those parts with **AnimationListener**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609974/android-animation-listener

Comment: Yeah I know, as I said in my question, I'd prefer an XML only solution as this would be the most elegant. I can't seen any reason why this would not be possible either.

Answer (score 0):

[ymz's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4062197/ymz) answer got my 90% of the way there, howevere there were two changes I had to make in order to get the desired effect. The main problem was that the first fade-out animation was skipped, to fix this make the following changes:

1. Remove the `fillEnabled="true"` attribute from the `AnimationSet`. I don't know why, but if this attribute is set to true on the Set rather than its children then the first alpha (fade-out) animation won't work. It will simply skip to the value of the `fromAlpha` on the second alpha animation (fade-in).
2. Add the `fillEnabled=true` attribute to the second (fade-in) alpha animation. This is because we need `fillBefore` to be set to false (as per the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#attr_android:fillEnabled) `fillBefore` will be ignored unless `fillEnabled` is set to true).

The final solution looks like this:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">

    <translate
        android:duration="800"
        android:fillAfter="false"
        android:fillEnabled="true"
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:toXDelta="-100%p"
        android:startOffset="0"/>

    <alpha
        android:duration="800"
        android:fillAfter="false"
        android:fillEnabled="true"
        android:fromAlpha="1"
        android:toAlpha="0"
        android:startOffset="0"/>

    <alpha
        android:duration="800"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:fillEnabled="true"
        android:fillBefore="false"
        android:fromAlpha="0.1"
        android:startOffset="800"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />
</set>
```