# Start an Activity after an animation has completed

Tags: android, animation

I have the following animation set in onClick. I am trying to start my activity after the animation is done, but it isn't working.

**CODE**

```
final ImageView iv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
iv1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.animation);
        iv1.startAnimation(anim);

        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClass(MainActivity.this, P2.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

**QUESTION**

How do I wait for the animation to complete before starting my activity?

Comment: no idea what you are asking here

Comment: This is the best question I have seen in a while.

Comment: I think what you are asking is how do you start a new activity after the animation has completed?

Answer (score 2):

Use animation listener

```
Animation.AnimationListener listener = new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClass(MainActivity.this, P2.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }
};
anim.setAnimationListener(listener);
iv1.startAnimation(anim);
```

Comment: while this should be accepted, an issue that i'm seeing is that the animation resets at the end of its animation. So if you fade something out, you'll get a few frames of it being visible before the activity launches. If you hackily set it to invisible in the `onAnimationEnd` it'll work, but it isn't a nice way to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AnimationListner for this. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html

Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8860057/3864698