# Image don'T get invisible

Tags: android

iI want that the image goes from the left side to the right side of the screen and then disappears
the translateanimation works. but with

img.setVisibility(View.GONE);

everything disappears, not only the image.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_animation);

        wander(img);

        img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    public void wander(ImageView img)
    {
        TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 400.0f,0.0f, 0.0f);
        animation.setDuration(500);
        animation.setRepeatCount(1);
        animation.setRepeatMode(1);
        animation.setFillAfter(true);
        img.startAnimation(animation);
    }
}
```

Comment: I must make a correction. With this code the image is never to see..

Comment: I want that the image goes from left to right and then goes

Comment: To catch the attention of the right people, add tags for animation and javascript

Comment: Javascript? Really now?

Comment: You hide the `ImageView` in `onCreate`. This's why you can't see it all the time. Animator won't show it for you if it's invisible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code starts the animation, then hides your image without waiting for the animation to finish. Use a listener like this to determine that the animation is over.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_animation);

        wander(img);
    }

    public void wander(ImageView img)
    {
        TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 400.0f,0.0f, 0.0f);
        animation.setDuration(500);
        animation.setRepeatCount(1);
        animation.setRepeatMode(1);
        animation.setFillAfter(false);
        animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            }

           @Override
           public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
               final ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_animation);
               img.setVisibiltiy(View.GONE);
           }

           @Override
           public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
           }
        });
        img.startAnimation(animation);
    }
}
```

For more information:
[Android Animation Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609974/android-animation-listener)

Comment: Thanks for the support.

Comment: But i am a beginner and i don't know how or where i have to put the animationlistener in my little Programm., Can you be so kind and show me?

Comment: If this worked for you remember to up vote and accept answer.

Comment: the setfillAfter from true to false.

Comment: Alright, updated the answer with false instead, press on the CheckBox next to it to mark it as the accepted answer.