# Use onBackPressed for fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, back

I have to show an animation when go back to previous fragment, so I must use a onBackPressed method. Since it's avaible just in activities, I tried to use a reference:

```
@Override
onBackPressed(){
super.onBackPressed();
infoFragment.onBackButtonPressed();
}
```

And in the InfoFragment I defined onBackButtonPressed method but it didn't work.
So I tried like this:

```
view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        view.requestFocus();
        view.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if(i==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
                    MainActivity mainActivity=(MainActivity)getActivity();
                    mainActivity.loadMainFragment();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

So, why it didn't work?

Comment: The first approach should work just fine, but I don't think that needs a custom back button listener. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886669/how-to-reverse-fragment-animations-on-backstack

Comment: `onBackPressed()` belongs to the Activity, not to the Fragment

Comment: Just use setCustomAnimations with FragmentTransaction.

Comment: Thanks @BLACKVVINE I resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to delay the back press event until your custom animation finishes, you should rewrite your code according to this snippet.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    infoFragment.onBackButtonPressed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    });
}
```

**What's that runnable?**

Your `onBackButtonPressed` method should get a runnable object and run it once the custom animation is over. This runnable is used as a callback function.

Using this way, you're delaying call to `super.onBackPressed()`, so you can first play your animation, then relaying the event to your activity's super class.

**When should I call this runnable?**

For your custom animation, attach an [animation listener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8860057/1841194) and call that runnable in `onAnimationEnd` method of it.