# Make something happen when ImageView animation is over

Tags: java, android, animation, imageview, android-animation

Let's say i have the following code:

`img1.animate().alpha(.5f).setDuration(300);`

And I want to execute this whenever the animation is over

`img1.setImageReasource(R.drawble.img_guitar);`

How do I do that??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Animation Listener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609974/android-animation-listener)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a listener to your animation:

```
imageView.animate().setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_guitar);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }
});
```

You can also use `withActionEnd(Runnable)`:

```
imageView.animate().withEndAction(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_guitar);
    }
})
```